# How to test linked icon with Rspec

Tags: rspec, ruby-on-rails-4

Need rewrite Rspec test for linked icons. Can't figure out how to refer properly to element

My current default test:

```
describe "Destroy action" do
  it {should have_link('Remove project', href: project_path(Project.first))}
  it "should be able to delete project" do
    expect do
      click_link('Remove project', match: :first)
    end.to change(Project, :count).by(-1)
  end
end
```

My helper method for delete image icon:

```
def delete_icon(height, width)
    link_to image_tag('delete.png', alt: 'Remove project', id:"delete_logo", height: "#    {height}", width: "#{width}"),@project, method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Burn it to the ground"}
end
```

Part of my view:

```
%div.comments_sidebar
    %h2 #{@project.title} #{edit_icon} #{delete_icon("700px", "30px")}
```

Comment: Do you want a "unit test" for the helper method or rewrite the integration test that you have?

Comment: I want to rewrite existing test. I changed simple link to icon and it of course caused prev. test failure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I think you shouldn't use an instance variable in a helper. So, I'd rewrite your helper method like that:

```
def delete_icon(project, height = <default height>, width = <default width>)
  link_to image_tag('delete.png', alt: 'Remove project', id: "delete_logo", height: height, width: width), project, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Burn it to the ground" }
end
```

In your test, using `nokogiri` gem, you could do something like that:

```
describe "delete_icon(project, height, width)" do
  let(:project) { <create a project> }

  it "creates a link with an image to remove given project" do
    link = Nokogiri::HTML(helper.delete_icon(project)).css('a')[0]
    image = link.css('img')[0]
    expect(link.attributes['href'].value).to eq(project_path(project))
    # check any other attributes for the link...
    expect(image.attributes['src'].value).to eq('/assets/delete.png')
    # check any other attributes for the image...
  end
end
```

You can add more examples passing a specific height and/or width to helper method and put this assertions in separate examples.